# No puedo grabar mas de 50 líneas de un excel en mysql con codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, hosting

Tengo una app web, desarrollada con codeigniter, dentro de la app, tengo una parte que importa datos desde un excel con el siguiente controlador:

```
public function VerCliente() {
    $config["upload_path"] = realpath(APPPATH."../files");
    $config["allowed_types"]= 'xls';
    $config["max_size"] = '0';
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
        $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(APPPATH.'../files/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name']);
    }
    unlink($config["upload_path"].'/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name']);
    $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();//estamos trayendo la coleccion de filas
    $header = array();
    $arr_data = array();
    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        # code...
        //aui estamos obteniendo las columnas a,b,c
        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
        //Aqui obtenemos el numero de filas
        $row    = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
        //
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
        if($row == 1){
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }else{
            $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
    }
$data = array(
  'titulo' => $this->titulo_controlador,
  'contenido' => 'sincronizar'.$this->controlador,
  'datas' => $arr_data,
  'breads' => array(array('ruta' => $this->url, 'titulo' => $this->titulo_controlador), array('ruta' => 'javascript:;', 'titulo' => 'Sincronizar')),
);
$this->load->view(THEME.TEMPLATE, $data);
}
```

Una vez cargado los datos en la vista, trato de grabar en la base de datos con el siguiente controlador:

```
public function GrabarCliente() {
    $contador = $this->input->post('contador');
    for($i=1; $i<=$contador; $i++) {
  $consulta = $this->Controlador_model->getValidar($this->input->post('suministro'.$i), $this->input->post('periodocomercial'.$i), $this->controlador);
  $sum = $this->Controlador_model->getSuministro($this->input->post('suministro'.$i), 'suministro');
  $ent = $this->Controlador_model->getEntrega($this->input->post('suministro'.$i), $this->input->post('periodocomercial'.$i), 'entrega');
  //$med = $this->Controlador_model->getMedidor($this->input->post('serie'.$i), 'medidor');
  if (!isset($sum)) {
    $suministro = array(
      "suministro" => $this->input->post('suministro'.$i),
      "delectrica" => $this->input->post('delectrica'.$i),
      "siselectrico" => $this->input->post('nombresiselectrico'.$i),
      "longitud" => $this->input->post('longitud'.$i),
      "latitud" => $this->input->post('latitud'.$i)
    );
    $this->Controlador_model->crear('suministro', $suministro);
  }

  $consultac = $this->Controlador_model->getSuministro($this->input->post('suministro'.$i), $this->controlador);
  if ($consultac) {
    $cactual = array(
      "periodocomercial" => $this->input->post('periodocomercial'.$i),
      "lanterior" => $this->input->post('ea'.$i),
      "mesesdeuda" => $this->input->post('mesesdeuda'.$i)
    );
    $this->Controlador_model->update($consultac, $cactual, $this->controlador);
  } else {
    $data = array(
      "suministro" => $this->input->post('suministro'.$i),
      "rutasuministro" => $this->input->post('rutasuministro'.$i),
      "nombres" => $this->input->post('nombres'.$i),
      "direccion" => $this->input->post('direccion'.$i),
      "delectrica" => $this->input->post('delectrica'.$i),
      "nombresiselectrico" => $this->input->post('nombresiselectrico'.$i),
      "nombrezonadm" => $this->input->post('nombrezonadm'.$i),
      "lanterior" => $this->input->post('ea'.$i),
      "mesesdeuda" => $this->input->post('mesesdeuda'.$i),
      "simbolo" => $this->input->post('simbolo'.$i),
      "periodocomercial" => $this->input->post('periodocomercial'.$i),
      "ea" => $this->input->post('ea'.$i),
      "cea" => $this->input->post('cea'.$i),
      "pea" => $this->input->post('pea'.$i),
      "marca" => $this->input->post('marca'.$i),
      "serie" => $this->input->post('serie'.$i),
      "tipoconexion" => $this->input->post('tipoconexion'.$i),
      "zona" => $this->input->post('zona'.$i),
      "longitud" => $this->input->post('longitud'.$i),
      "latitud" => $this->input->post('latitud'.$i)
    );
    $this->Controlador_model->crear($this->controlador, $data);
  }
```

Y este es el model

```
public function crear($tabla, $data) {
return $this->db->insert($tabla, $data);
```

}

La aplicación está en un hosting, ya modifiqué **max_execution_time** , **max_input_time** y **upload_max_filesize** y aún así no consigo grabar en la BD mas de 50 registros, teniendo en cuenta que los datos que tengo que guardar son en promedio 1500 por mes, por favor si alguien podría ayudarme con este tema.

**--------------------AGREGADO--------------------**

Primera petición, mostrar los datos en una vista
[image: Primera petición]

Segunda petición, enviar los datos a la base de datos

[image: Segunda petición, guardar en la base de datos]

Comment: 1,500 registros no es nada, a no ser que sea un hosting gratuito y tengas restricciones ¿?  ¿Hay algún mensaje de error por alguna parte? Revisa el log de errores.

Comment: existe alguna forma en la que puedas ver el sql que está por ejecutarse?? pueda que el error esté ahí

Comment: Revisé el log de consola, y no tengo errores, efectivamente @A. Cedano, 1500 no son nada

Comment: @DavElsanto no encuentro forma de mostrar el sql a ejecutarse

Comment: Es probable que si trata de insertar los datos por un SP este sobrepase el tamaño maximo del varchar a insertar. Revisa los logs de la DB.

Comment: No uso SP, estoy trabajando con CI puro, fíjate el model, uso la función insert de CI

Comment: No uso frameworks por lo que desde ese punto de vista no puedo ayudarte. Pero, en cuanto al manejo de los datos ¿has pensando en usar transacciones, capturando los posibles errores y mostrándolos? Siempre es aconsejable usar transacciones cuando se trata de datos masivos.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, primero lees el Excel, luego lo muestras en el navegador y luego vuelves a enviar los datos para insertarlos? Puede ser que excedas el límite para el tamaño de la segunda la petición y trunque los datos. Prueba a depurar si recibes todos los datos en antes de insertar.

Comment: @Xerif exactamente, describiste el proceso tal cual, al depurar es como si el tiempo de ejecución se truncara y hace que no muestre nada, absolutamente nada, es como si la segunda petición no llegara ni a ejecutarse, pero en cambio si solo pongo 50 líneas, se pueden ver todos los datos a insertar.

Comment: Fijate si en la opciones de red del navegador te devuelve por casualidad un `414 Request-URI Too Long` o un 500 o algun otro error de la peticion

Comment: Devuelve un `302 Moved Temporarily` aunque en todas mis peticiones tengo esa respuesta, ahora respecto a cualquier otro error, no encuentro otro más, devuelve como si todo estuviera normal